# Docusign embed template edit view

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to embed template edit view in my application. [API Reference](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Templates/TemplateViews/createEdit)

Below is the source code to retrieve template edit view url using php client

```
$templatesApi = new TemplatesApi($apiClient);

# Generate the embed template edit view
$returnUrlRequest = new ReturnUrlRequest();
$returnUrlRequest->setReturnUrl('http://localhost:8080/success');

$editViewUrl = $templatesApi->createEditView($this->getAccountId(), $templateId, $returnUrlRequest)->getUrl();
```

& it returns below edit view url

> https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=3c5a3d84...&DocuEnvelope=[template_id]

But when I load the above url, it redirects to docusign home page. Where I'm expecting it to show the template edit view.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that your url was different from what you posted, right?
can you try to do this directly with the API without using the client?
use postman to post to /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/views/edit and see what url you get and if that one also doesn't work to try to isolate the issue.
Also, suggest to try create new template for testing purposes just in case the template you tried has an issue

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's an issue with the templateId, you need to make sure you provide the correct templateId to the API. This should look like a GUID and the URL you show here doesn't have it.